# Minimizing over permutations

Tags: optimization, permutations

Fix $a=(a_1,...,a_n)^T,b=(b_1,...b_n)^T \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  Assume WLOG $a_1\geq...\geq a_n$, $b_1 \geq ... \geq b_n$.  Let $s$ be a permutation of the indices $\{ 1,...,n \}$. 
Intuitively, the way to minimize $\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i-b_{s(i)})^2$ would be to choose $s$ to be the identity permutation. So I'm having trouble proving this or generating a counterexample, since I'm unfamiliar to optimizing over permutations.  Some help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider swapping $2$ different elements in $b$. What happens to the 2 terms affected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that since $\sum_{i=1}^na_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^nb_{s(i)}$ are constant expressions regardless of $s$, we want to maximise $\sum_{i=1}^nab_{s(i)}$. This is maximised when $s$ brings $b$ into a sorted state, as this is the [Rearrangement Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality).

Comment: I think I see it now.  Let $b_s = (b_{s(1)},...,b_{s(n)})$.  Then $\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i-b_{s(i)})^2$ = $||a-b_s||_2^2$ =$a^T a + b_s^T b_s -2a^T b_s$, so we need to *maximize* $a^T b_s$ over permutations s, so we can use the Rearrangement Ineq as you pointed out.

Comment: Yes, that seems correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can always think of permutations in terms of transpositions -- swapping of two elements.

Can you say what happens if you swap $b_i$ and $b_j$?

It might help to assume (without loss of generality) that $a_1\leq a_2\leq\ldots\leq a_n$.  What happens in the swap if $b_i>b_j$?  What if $b_i<b_j$?